# How to add an additional string in Spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner

```
private Spinner mSpnrCustomer;
private List<String> mCustomerList = new ArrayList<String>();
mCustomerList= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.customer_names));
mSpnrCustomer.setAdapter(new SpinnerRoomTypeAdapter(context,mCustomerList));
```

Here the Spinner is populated successfully with the corresponding data in the ArrayList. I want to add an additional string other than what's in the ArrayList at the bottom such as "`CreateUser`". On selecting this I need it to open a popup. How can I do this?

Comment: try to do notifydatasetchanged on adapter after adding

Comment: Please post your logcat and at which line it throws exception?

Answer (score 0):

you need to **[notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())** the adapter about changes in the list

```
mCustomerList = new ArrayList<String>();
//populate the list
mCustomerList = 
Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.customer_names));
//set the adapter
mSpnrCustomer.setAdapter(new SpinnerRoomTypeAdapter(context,mCustomerList));
//add something to the List
mCustomerList.add("Foo");
//notify the adapter
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

now you have the problem that you set the adapter as an anonymous instance... then you will need a variable for that

Comment: I am getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 0):

Its simple :

```
private Spinner mSpnrCustomer;
private List<String> mCustomerList = new ArrayList<String>();
   mCustomerList= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.customer_names));
String createUser= "CreateUser";
mCustomerList.add(createUser);
        mSpnrCustomer.setAdapter(new SpinnerRoomTypeAdapter(context,mCustomerList));
```

Explanation: You have an ArrayList  that holds String objects. If you want to add new Strings to it you can use ArrayList method add to do it.

Comment: tried this But getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.customer_name)));
list.add("CreateUser");

mSpnrCustomer.setAdapter(new SpinnerRoomTypeAdapter(context,list));
```

Comment: @Noufal please check now , you are getting unsupportedoperation exception because Arrays.asList() returns a fixed size list , you can't add element in this

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Spinner mSpnrCustomer;
private List<String> mCustomerList = new ArrayList<String>();
customer_names.add("Value");
   mCustomerList= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.customer_names));
        mSpnrCustomer.setAdapter(new SpinnerRoomTypeAdapter(context,mCustomerList));
```

Add one line code *customer_names.add("Value");* before calling spinner